# Updating related models in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working with a database in Laravel app using Eloquent ORM. I have two Model classes - Match and Point. One match has many points, so I define relationships like this:

```
class Match extends Model {
   ...
   public function points() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Point', 'match_id');
   }
}

class Point extends Model {
   ...
   public function match() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Match', 'match_id');
   }
}
```

Firstly, I retrieve one Match model from DB like this. You can see I'm also retrieving related points by calling `->with(...)` method.

```php
$match = Match::where('id', $matchID)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($userID) {
        $query->where("player1_id", $userID)->orWhere('player2_id', $userID);
    })
    ->with('points')->first();
```

Then, I would like to create and save one Point (related to my Match) and update Match model so that I can return a response with actual points of a match (including the newly created Point). Is there any way how to do that? Or I should get the match from DB again? It would make two queries to DB, so it doesn't seem very effective.

Comment: You can reload the relationship: `$match->load('points');`

Comment: As Jonas said, you can use `$match->load('points')`. But if you need to reduce calls to the DB, you can use `$match->points->add($new_point);`